# How to center a Popup Div (horizontally and vertically) on wordpress/woocommerce site

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress website with WooCommerce. The theme is woodmart.

See Image please. I want to add a notify me button with custom text.

[image: Original layout]

So, in the functions.php, i add:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_custom_sale_text', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_custom_sale_text', 10 );

function woocommerce_custom_sale_text()
{
  global $post,$product;
  if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
  echo '<div ' ;
  echo 'class="openPopUp wd-buy-now-btn button alt add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart add_no_loop" ';
  // This is the "notify me when back in stock" button
  // i set the class list to include "openPopUp", so that I can refer to it via 
  // javascript. this is the "notify me" button.
  // the other classes are copyied from the theme to match style
  
  echo 'style="position: absolute;top: 10%; left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -90%);-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -90%);"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Verfügbarkeitsalarm</div>';
  // this moves the button a bit lower on the product cell
  // in grid view, as shown in the picture.
        

  echo '<div id="wc_bis_product_form" class="popup" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%);';
  echo 'z-index:10000;background-color:#FDFDFD;width:1000px;padding:20px;border: 4px solid;border-color:rgb(255,153,0)" onclick="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();">' ;
  // this is the actual popup container div
  // it shows a textbox for email and a submit button
  // since this is shown on top of an item in the grid
  // I must make sure that
  // a) it is on top of everything and opaque (i.e. solid fill color)
  // b) click on the input textbox or the button should not send a click event to the
  // parent cell in the grid view where the product was

  echo '<p class="wc_bis_form_title" onclick="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();">Möchten Sie benachrichtigt werden, wenn dieses Produkt wieder auf Lager ist?</p>'; // Text
  echo '<input type="text" id="wc_bis_email" name="wc_bis_email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" onclick="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();">'; //email input
  echo '<button class="button wc_bis_send_form" type="button" id="wc_bis_send_form" name="wc_bis_send_form" onclick="$(\'#wc_bis_product_form\').fadeOut(5000);">';
  echo 'Ja        </button>'; // submit button
  echo '</div>';

  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='https://emee.de/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-back-in-stock-notifications/assets/js/frontend/wc-bis-main.min.js?ver=1.4.3' id='wc-bis-main-js'></script>"; // need this to call on the back-in-stock functions of a plugin
    }

}
```

In the javascript, i have:

```
 var notifyBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('openPopUp');
        if (notifyBtns) {

                for (var inot = 0; inot < notifyBtns.length; inot++) {

                        var nBtn = notifyBtns[inot];
                        nBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $('#wc_bis_product_form').fadeIn(1000);
                                var left = (screen.width/2);//-(w/2);
                                var top = (screen.height/2);//-(h/2);
                                $('#wc_bis_product_form').left = left;
                                $('#wc_bis_product_form').top = e.pageY;
                                $('#wc_bis_product_form').transform = translate(left,e.pageY);


                        });

                }

        }
```

This works. this adds a "Notify me" button to every product out of stock. Clicking on the button opens the popup div.

**The Problem:**

Sometimes, a customer will scroll down, and somewhere near near the bottom of the grid view, the customer might find an item out of stock. If now, the notify me button is clicked, the popup div opens at a location that is approximately centered to the original view, which is outside the current viewport.

In concrete terms, consider the original grid layout. I had one unavailable item in the top row, center column. If I click on the "Notify me" button, I get this:

[image: Popup div opened]

So this is fine and good enough.

But, if I scroll down, so that the bottom row (all 3 items unavailable) is in the viewport and the top row is out of viewport of browser, and then click on any of the three "Notify me" buttons for the bottom row, this happens:

[image: Popup outside viewport]

The popup still opened, but at the same place like the top row, before I scrolled.

**What I need**
I need the popup div to open near the location of the mouse click on the document. That is, if I scrolled down so that the second row is in viewport, then the pop up will also open in the same viewport.

Please note, that I want inline css, and I really really dont want to mess witht he theme css files. Thank you.
All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is not a PHP/Wordpress issue, I'd highly suggest converting your PHP code into a functional, runnable snippet with HTML, JS and CSS. Otherwise, people have to decode all your PHP and convert it to HTML before they can even test your code, which most people won't be doing. You should include your CSS as well.

Comment: Isn't `position: fixed;` instead of `absolute` for your popup what you are looking for?

Comment: @Awesom-o - thank you. That is in the right direction, but now the popup is flickering. Even though i have a high z-index

Comment: When is the flickering happening? Constantly? Or when you scroll? Or?

Comment: @Awesom-o : 1. When I scroll, and 2. if the mouse pointer is on top of an item. If the cursor is outside the grid view, no problem ... I found an old bug: https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/issues/45. But not sure if this is relevant 11 years later

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, is someone needs it.

Here is the solution:

```
var notifyBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('openPopUp');
    if (notifyBtns) {
        
        var pups = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
        if (pups) {
    
            for (var inot = 0; inot < notifyBtns.length; inot++) {
                
                var nBtn = notifyBtns[inot];
                console.log("button found");
            
                let ixx = inot;         
              // previously, i was picking them up by id.
              // that only identifies the first button.
              // now, we pick them by class.
              
              // however, in order for the attached eventlistener
              // to have an unique ID; we need to supply the index of the button
              // just supplying the button index from the for loop will not work, 
              // because by the time the eventlistener is called,
              // the for loop is out of scope
              // so create a specific variable inside the scope corresponding to the index
              // and send that to a named function as an argument
              // the named function should contain code that relies on the index.

                if (inot < pups.length) {
                    var nPup = pups[inot];
                    console.log("popup found");
                    nBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        showPopup(ixx, e.pageX,e.pageY);
                        console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);

                    });
                    console.log("listener added");
                }           
                
            }

        }
                


    }
```

Then, inside `showPopup`, i do :

```
function showPopup( inot, x, y) {
    
    var pups = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
    
    for(var ii = 0; ii < pups.length; ii++) 
        pups[ii].style.display = 'none';            // close all open popups
    
    console.log(pups);
    console.log(inot);
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
        
    pups[inot].style.display = 'block';
                        
    console.log("display changed");
                        
    var top = y ;
    var left= x ;
        
    pups[inot].style.top = "50%";
    pups[inot].style.left= "50%";
    pups[inot].style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
    console.log("position changed");
    console.log(pups[inot]);


}
```

Unfortunately `position:fixed` causes more trouble than it solves. So I remain with  `position:absolute`.